# ScalaTest - how to check that all items of sequence match the predicate?

Tags: scala, scalatest

Is there a way to show better error message? For example, below code

```scala
it should "check that items satisfy predicate" in {
  List(1,2,3,4,5,6).forall(x => x < 5) should equal (true)
}
```

only gives me following error without any description:

> "false did not equal true"

Predicate can not only be `least` expression, but any other function. For `least` I found https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#inspectorShorthands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can not only be least expression, but any other function

Using [inspector](https://www.scalatest.org/scaladoc/3.2.5/org/scalatest/Inspectors.html) try

```
forAll (xs) { x => assert(pred(x)) }
```

where `pred: T => Boolean`, which output informative error message with failing index and predicate, something like

```
- should check that items satisfy predicate *** FAILED ***
  forAll failed, because: 
    at index 4, pred(x) was false (HelloSpec.scala:41) 
  in List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) (HelloSpec.scala:41)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  List(1,2,3,4,5,6).foreach { _ should be < 5 }
```

Comment: Didn't try it out, but are you sure that it parses? I somehow have the feeling that it should be `should be < 5`, as in this [example about `beWithinTolerance`](https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers). `value(_) method(should) value(be) method(<) value(5)`, otherwise method invocations and values aren't alternating.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin yeah, you are right ... I never know which way will compile in each particular case, gotta just try one and see :)

Comment: I've updated the comment: It's actually quite easy to spot, because all those scala-edsl's from the early days always have the structure of `expression methodName expression methodName expression` etc. I didn't "remember" anything about `shouldBe` or `should be`, I just checked whether it alternates or not.

Comment: Yeah ... still gotta remember that `should` is a method, and `be` s not ... while `shouldBe` still is :D

Answer (score 0):

You can change the question from

> "check that items satisfy predicate"

to

> "check that all the items in the list are smaller than 5"

and then the answer is more meaningful.

If you want a more meaningful answer, you can call `fail`, like

```
fail("I've got a bad feeling about this.")
```

You can also use assertions in many ways, read [this](https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_assertions) for more information. Example:

```
assume(database.isAvailable, "The database was down again")
```